# Setting large image as a background-image in a smaller div not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2LTYY/). I am trying to set the background-image of a div as follows:

```
.close-button{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_close_exit_delete_small.png');
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

here's the div:

```
<div class="close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

why is this not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) i.e `background-size:25px;` or `background-size:contain;` to your image since it is much bigger than your div's dimensions.

```
.close-button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_close_exit_delete_small.png');
    background-size:25px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8xZA8/)**

On a side note this image is too big to be an icon, you can try considering the usage of image sprites to consolidate all your icons to one image file and just use css background position to select them.

Answer (score 2):

You image is bigger than your div. Change the width and height of the div, you will see the background image. Or you have to use a smaller background image.

```
.close-button 
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brightmix/128/monotone_close_exit_delete_small.png');
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2LTYY/4/